# how to use consumer correctly in flutter provider package

Tags: flutter, provider, consumer, changenotifier

This is the error message

```
: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<PageOffsetNotifier>(dirty,
: dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<PageOffsetNotifier>]):
: The method 'unary-' was called on null.
: Receiver: null
: Tried calling: unary-()
```

this is the class with consumer

```
class LeopardImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<PageOffsetNotifier>(
      builder: (context,notifier,child) => Positioned(
          width:300, left: -notifier.offset,
          child: child,
      ),
      child: Image.asset('assets/leopard.png'),
    );
  }
}
```

here **PageOffsetNotifier** is the class which extends with **ChangeNotifier** and passed on to **ChangeNotifierProvider**

the **notifier** will detect the change in offset value while swiping one page to another and perform the desired function.....

Please tell me what I'm missing or done wrong in the **consumer**, as a result, I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

To Pass the context from a page to another using provider. Then it's always wise to use its object

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
    value: object from Provider,
    child: the page you want to move
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent widget of this will be :

```
ChangeNotiferProvider<ClassName>(
    
   oncreate: (context)=>ClassName(),
),
```

With this you can use consumer inside.